# Python/Pandas: .CSV Data Cleanup For Migration

Tags: python, pandas, database-migration, data-cleaning

I'm a fairly new python/pandas user, and I have been tasked with the cleanup of a roughly 5,000 row csv of records, and the subsequent migration of the records into a sql database.

The contents are individual people's personal information(which prevents me from posting it for reference) and their 'seat' occupation information,  but the file has been... mismanaged... over the years, and has ended up looking like this:

```
#Sect1         Sect2        Sect3        Seat#
L/L/L/L   320/320/319/321  D/C/D/C   1-2/1-2/1-2/1-2
  V             602           -            1-6
  T             101           F            1&3
  R             158           -            3* 4
  U             818           4            Ds9R
```

With that individual's personal information in four columns not shown to the left.

In reality, even just the top row from the selection above should actually be:

```
    #Sect1     Sect2   Sect3   Seat#
      L         320      D       1
      L         320      D       2
      L         320      C       1
      L         320      C       2
      L         319      D       1
      L         319      D       2
      L         321      C       1
      L         321      C       2
```

with the '-'s implying that it's 'through' not 'and'. (For example; the second row in my original example would be Seat# 1 ***through*** Seat# 6, not Seat# 1 and 6.

I should also note that there's no unique ID/Index for these individuals, and it's purely based on First/Last name.

I've been attempting to break some of this up, and have limited success with

```
df1 = df1.drop('Sect2', axis=1).join(df1['Sect2'].str.split('/', expand=True).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename('Sect2'))
```

but this eventually ends up creating erroneous records such as

```
#Sect1     Sect2   Sect3   Seat#
  L         319      C       1
```

In the end, my question is; Is using a script to clean this data even possible?  I'm rapidly running out of ideas, and really don't want to have to do this manually, but I also don't want to waste any more time trying to script this out if it's a pointless endeavor.

Comment: it seems the seat section does not follow any pattern, or is there?

Comment: There is no pattern, no.  Each Section has between 4 and 16 seats, and the naming convention varies from section to section as well.

Comment: @Wonky were you able to get the code provided in my answer to work for you?

Comment: @Ghoti Apologies for the slow recognition of your efforts.  Your script fixed the problem described.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should address the two issues described in your post. Should be selective enough to avoid misinterpreting rows, but some manual curation will likely still be necessary.

Basic concept is to iterate row by row, processing as much as possible before proceeding. First priority is to split rows containing character "/". If none is found, range value "-" is interpreted. The `while` loop permits gradual improvement. For example, the code would convert 1-3 into 1/2/3, then re-read the same row and split it into 3 different rows.

```
# build demo dataframe
d = {"Sect1": ["L/L/L/L", "V", "T", "R", "U"], 
     "Sect2": ["320/320/319/321", "602", "101", "158", "818"],
     "Sect3": ["D/C/D/C", "-", "F", "-", "4"],
     "Seat#": ["1-2/1-2/1-2/1-2", "1-6", "1&3", "3* 4", "Ds9R"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


index = 0
while index < len(df):
    len_df = len(df)
    row_li = [df.iloc[index][x] for x in df.head()]
    # extract separated values
    sep_li = [x.split("/") for x in row_li]
    sep_min, sep_max = len(min(sep_li, key=lambda x: len(x))), len(max(sep_li, key=lambda x: len(x)))
    # extract range values
    num_range_li = [re.findall("^\d+\-\d+$|$", x)[0].split("-") for x in row_li]
    num_range_max = len(max(num_range_li, key=lambda x: len(x)))
    # create temporary dictionary representing current row
    r = {}
    for i, head in enumerate(df.head()):
        r[head] = row_li[i]
    # separated values treatment -> split into distinct rows
    if sep_min > 1 and sep_min == sep_max:
        for i, head in enumerate(df.head()):
            r[head] = sep_li[i]
        row_df = pd.DataFrame(data=r)
        df = df.append(row_df, ignore_index=True)
    # range values treatment -> convert into separated values
    elif num_range_max > 1:
        for part in (1, 2):
            for idx, header in enumerate(df.head()):
                if len(num_range_li[idx]) > 1:
                    split_li = [str(x) for x in range(int(num_range_li[idx][0]), int(num_range_li[idx][1])+1)]
                    # convert range values to separated values
                    if part == 1:
                        r[header] = "/".join(split_li)
                    # multiply other values
                    else:
                        for i, head in enumerate(df.head()):
                            if i != idx:
                                r[head] = "/".join([r[head] for x in range(len(split_li))])
        row_df = pd.DataFrame(data=r, index=[0])
        df = df.append(row_df, ignore_index=True)

    # if no new rows are added, increment
    if len(df) == len_df:
        index += 1
    # if rows are added, drop current row
    else:
        df = df.iloc[:index].append(df.iloc[index+1:])

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   Sect1 Sect2 Sect3 Seat#
0      T   101     F   1&3
1      R   158     -  3* 4
2      U   818     4  Ds9R
4      V   602     -     1
5      V   602     -     2
6      V   602     -     3
7      V   602     -     4
8      V   602     -     5
9      V   602     -     6
10     L   320     D     1
11     L   320     D     2
12     L   320     C     1
13     L   320     C     2
14     L   319     D     1
15     L   319     D     2
16     L   321     C     1
17     L   321     C     2
```

Comment: This fixed the problem described!  Thank you @Ghoti,  as you noted, there will still be a bit of manual cleanup required, but this is a huge head start, thank you.  I'll study this script in depth to ensure I understand the mechanics for next time a project like this comes up.